# Gridfield not populate with ArrayList when not in public function getCMSFields

Tags: php, arraylist, silverstripe, tabular

When I create GridField within admin console - everything is ok  - I cam populate gridfield via classic method (ex. Member::get() - - or via ArrayList -

```
$al1 = new ArrayList();
$records = DB::query("SELECT * from Member where id<10");
while ($rec = $records->next()) {
    $al1->push(new ArrayData($rec));
}       
$grid = new GridField('Pages', 'All pages', $al1)
```

Both methods are working ok.
However, If I try to create GridField on user page - - presented in a form - - somehow the second method (where GridField should be populated by ArrayList - is not working).

```
$gridField = new GridField('pages1', 'All pages1', Member::get(), $config);
```

- woks ok, but the method where I create ArrayList old-fashioned way:

```
$al = new ArrayList();
$records = DB::query("SELECT * from Member where id<10");
while ($rec1 = $records->next()) {
    $al->push(new ArrayData($rec));
}
```

I get an error when I try to render gridfield through:

```
return new Form($this, "AllSubmissions", new FieldList($gridField), new FieldList());
```

The error I am getting is:

> [Warning] Missing argument 1 for ArrayData::__construct() GET /ss340/gridfield-test/gridfield-underr-grid/ Line 27 in C:\wamp\www\ss340\framework\view\ArrayData.php

Since I need data from external database to populate gridfield on non admin pages, I am desperate to get the solution for this. 
If someone can provide me alternative method to show/edit tabular data in Silverstripe - -would appreciate very much.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked up your error. It comes from the gridfield that tries to use this function:

```
public function getDisplayFields($gridField) {
    if(!$this->displayFields) {
        return singleton($gridField->getModelClass())->summaryFields();
    }
    return $this->displayFields;
}
```

If you are giving an ArrayList with ArrayData in it, it is trying to create a singleton of `ArrayData`. This causes an error because ArrayData expects an object or an array.

My oppinion is still to use my old answer, this would give you a DataList and you won't have to go through the trouble.

**Old Answer**

Why go through all the trouble and not just make use of SilverStripe's ORM with [SearchFilters](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/model/searchfilters/)?

```
$dbConfig = [
    "type" => 'MySQLDatabase',
    "server" => 'localhost',
    "username" => '',
    "password" => '',
    "database" => '',
    "path" => '',
]; // fill this array with your other database configuration

//connect
DB::connect($dbConfig);

$members = Member::get()->filter('ID:LessThan', 10);

//reset to your own database
global $databaseConfig;
DB::connect($databaseConfig);
```

One last note; when 'developing' it is recommended to put SilverStripe in 'dev mode'. In the comments you say you are getting a Server Error (500) which indicates your SilverStripe is not in dev mode, or your `error_reporting` is not enabled. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38185403/6251886) could help you doing that.

Comment: I appreciate your effort - but as mentioned I would like to populate GridField with data from external db, so I can't use ORM method. I did turn on error_reporting and posted the answer about error. However - still does not make sence that I can populate gridfield in admin section with classic method but not in user section. Regards

Comment: I updated my answer for you. With the code you can switch between databases.

Answer (score 0):

OK, from the error you posted:

```
 * var array
 * see ArrayData::_construct() / protected $array; 
/*
 * @param object|array $value An associative array, or an object with simple properties. 
 * Converts object properties to keys of an associative array. 
 */
public function __construct($value) {
    if (is_object($value)) { 
        $this->array = get_object_vars($value); 
    } elseif (ArrayLib::is_associative($value)) { 
        $this->array = $value; 
    } elseif (is_array($value) && count($value) === 0) { 
        $this->array = array();
```

This error looks incomplete, but I noticed your submitted code is:

```
$al = new ArrayList();
$records = DB::query("SELECT * from Member where id<10");
while ($rec1 = $records->next()) {
    $al->push(new ArrayData($rec));
}
```

But `$rec` is not defined and so likely you are not passing a valid constructor argument to `new ArrayData()`

try:

```
$al = new ArrayList();
$records = DB::query("SELECT * from Member where id<10");
while ($rec = $records->next()) {
    $al->push(new ArrayData($rec));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort - I noticed that I made an error rec1<>rec. However, even with the code you provided, the error remains  - and the warning I am getting is: [Warning] Missing argument 1 for ArrayData::__construct(). As with connecting to external DB - I cannot use Member::get() - - since Member table in external DB is not a class - just a table with some data. Regards,GRega

Comment: I know how to connect to external DB - however - tables in that db are not classes and i can not query them by ORMmethod.

Comment: Of error is that you have a missing argument for array data constructor, then you aren't passing anything in to the constructor. Either your var is empty or you have a syntax error you aren't showing us

Comment: I really appreciate your effort  -- but it just does not make sense:'code'

Comment: it just doesn't make sense - same piece of code work fine in admin section  -that is within getDMSfield function - - but keeps returning the above mentioned error when used in nonadmin function - - again : no problem if I use Member::get() syntax. If anyone has an idea how to populate gridfield with data from external db and display it on the (non admin) site - - I would relly appreciate it. I am quite new in ss and loving it so far (before working with Drupal) and looking forward - -best regards

Comment: Guys - still no solution here! I can't use Member::get() way of quering external database. And again - - can please someone show me the direction to my problem - populate gridfield that is not in getCMSFields? I am really sruck here.

Comment: If the code you posted is what you're using then it is the syntax error.

Comment: The error you're saying you're getting is because you aren't supplying an argument to arraydata when you instantiate it in the while loop.

Comment: If I rephrase my problem: how to populate $al (ArrayList) with values from $records - - I see that query works ok, just ArrayList doesn't get filled??

Comment: How do I supply an argument to arraydata when instantinate it in the while loop?